# How can I install Bootstrap on Jimdo?

Tags: php, content-management-system, bootstrapping

I would like to use Bootstrap module inside [Jimdo CMS](//github.com/Jimdo/jimphle-bootstrap).

Is it possible to insert this PHP module easily?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score -1):

You simply cannot install php based code into the jimdo CMS. That is because the CMS is closed, you have no access and no means to do so. All you can add to such a system is content (text, pictures and the like), some styles (if required) and some javascript.